# Do we have to remove onClickListener?

Tags: android, onclicklistener

this looks like a simple question, but I just want to know,

do we have to remove `onClickListener` or in my case is `TabListener` say when an activity is destroyed or paused?

for example here is my code:

```
package code.tabnav;

import adapter.SectionsPagerAdapter;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

import com.example.tabnav.R;

public class Home extends FragmentActivity {

private ViewPager mViewPager;
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private ActionBar.TabListener tabListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    /* On Create method */

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager(), this);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);

    mViewPager
            .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            });

    getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
        public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
                FragmentTransaction ft) {
        }

        public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
                FragmentTransaction ft) {
        }
    };
    addNewTab("Home", tabListener);
    addNewTab("Latest", tabListener);
    addNewTab("Find", tabListener);
    addNewTab("Download", tabListener);
}

private final void addNewTab(String name, ActionBar.TabListener tabListener) {
    getActionBar().addTab(
            getActionBar().newTab().setText(name)
                    .setTabListener(tabListener));
}
```

}

any information would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to remove a listener. It's just an object, and it should be garbage-collected if it's no longer being referenced. Are you running into a problem?

Comment: no problem actually, I just think whether we have to remove it or not.. I have googled it and could not find a good explanation,thank your for your information..

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are making your own listener then you have remove that listener else it will hold that activity on memory heap, but for default listeners java handles it when that activity is destroyed.